# Feodra 22 - Want to build CouchDB

Tags: build, erlang, couchdb, fedora

I want to build CouchDB1.6.1 on Fedora22.
On ./configure there are no Errors and I get the Message "Run `make && make install` ".
It doens´t matter what I run, always get an error.

**This is the error by `make`.
Does anyone knows what to do?**

```
`[Tatjana@localhost apache-couchdb-1.6.1]$ make
    make  all-recursive
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1'
Making all in bin
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/bin'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/bin'
ln -s -f "/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src/couchdb/priv/couchjs" "couchjs_dev"
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/bin'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/bin'
Making all in etc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc'
Making all in couchdb
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/couchdb'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/couchdb'
Making all in default
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/default'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/default'
Making all in init
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/init'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/init'
Making all in launchd
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/launchd'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/launchd'
Making all in logrotate.d
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/logrotate.d'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/logrotate.d'
Making all in windows
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/windows'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc/windows'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/etc'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src'
Making all in couch_dbupdates
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src/couch_dbupdates'
/usr/local/bin/erlc -I../../src/couchdb -o ebin/   src/couch_dbupdates.erl;
src/couch_dbupdates.erl: internal error in expand_module;
crash reason: undef

  in function  erl_parse:new_anno/1
     called as erl_parse:new_anno({function,0,module_info,0,
           [{clause,0,[],[],
                    [{call,0,
                           {remote,0,{atom,0,erlang},{atom,0,get_module_info}},
                           [{atom,0,couch_dbupdates}]}]}]})
  in call from sys_pre_expand:'-module_predef_funcs/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/1 (sys_pre_expand.erl, line 119)
  in call from sys_pre_expand:module_predef_funcs/1 (sys_pre_expand.erl, line 119)
  in call from sys_pre_expand:module/2 (sys_pre_expand.erl, line 81)
  in call from compile:expand_module/1 (compile.erl, line 1202)
  in call from compile:'-internal_comp/4-anonymous-1-'/2 (compile.erl, line 295)
  in call from compile:fold_comp/3 (compile.erl, line 321)
  in call from compile:internal_comp/4 (compile.erl, line 305)
Makefile:517: recipe for target 'ebin/couch_dbupdates.beam' failed
make[3]: *** [ebin/couch_dbupdates.beam] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src/couch_dbupdates'
Makefile:687: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src'
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Tatjana/apache-couchdb-1.6.1'
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple versions of erl installed and got the same error. Removing the old versions (rm -rf /usr/local/lib/erlang) then make install the correct version for CouchDB and I was all set.